# Space complexity of Partition Label Problem

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity, memory-efficient

A string S of lowercase letters is given. We want to partition this string into as many parts as possible so that each letter appears in at most one part, and return a list of integers representing size of each part.

```
Input: S = "ababcbacadefegdehijhklij"
Output: [9,7,8]
```

Explanation:
The partition is "ababcbaca", "defegde", "hijhklij".
This is a partition so that each letter appears in at most one part.

A partition like "ababcbacadefegde", "hijhklij" is incorrect, because it splits S into less parts.

Below is my Code for the above problem:

```
class Solution {
public List<Integer> partitionLabels(String S) {

    char[] st = S.toCharArray();
    int k=0,c=0;
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer> ();

    for(int i=0 ; i<st.length ; i++)
    {
        int idx = S.lastIndexOf(st[i]);
        if(visited.add(i) && idx>i && idx>k)
        {
            k = Math.max(k,idx);
            visited.add(k);

        }
        else if(i == k)
        {
            res.add(i-c+1);
            c=i+1;
            k++;
        }
    }

    return res;

}
}
```

The above code works and the time complexity of the above code in O(n) since it visits each element once.

But what is the space complexity? Since I am using a Char array whose size is the same as the the String S and a Set whose Max size can be the size of the String S, is it also O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

As you only use one dimensional arrays and lists your space complexity is O(n).

But your time complexity is O(n²) because `S.lastIndexOf(st[i]);` is O(n).

If you wanted also time to be O(n) you have to pre-process the string once (= O(n)) to determine the last occurence of each character, f.i. with a map to keep the retrieving time O(1).